# Primefaces range slider max and min values

Tags: validation, events, primefaces, slider

I need to know from which element is the value that I get in the event from a range slider. I have the following code:

```
<h:outputText id="displayValues" value="#{myBean.min} - #{myBean.max}"/>
<p:slider
  id="mySlider"
  for="min,max"
  display="displayValues"
  range="true"
  displayTemplate=" {min} - {max}" 
  minValue="#{myBean.value1}"  
  maxValue="#{myBean.value2}" >
  <p:ajax event="slideEnd" listener="#{simuladorBean.onSlideEnd}"/>
</p:slider>
<h:inputHidden id="min" value="#{myBean.min}"/>
<h:inputHidden id="max" value="#{myBean.max}" />
```

In myBean with event.getValue(), I know the new value from the slider that I move, but I need to know if this new value is from max or min slider.
can someone help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when a form is submitted, the `inputHidden` max and min are also submitted. But due to you using `p:ajax` on the slider and since the default `process` of a `p:ajax` is `@this`, the `inputHidden` fields are not submitted. If you change the `p:ajax` to

```
<p:ajax event="slideEnd" process="@this, min, max" listener="#{simuladorBean.onSlideEnd}"/>
```

(or by wrapping the whole xhtml block above in a container and processing that)

The min and max **are** submitted and in the `onSlideEnd` you can compare the value you get in the event with the min and max and determine which one changed.

**See also**

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)
- https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=28771

Comment: Thanks a lot, yesterday I try only with process="@this" and process="min, max" following some examples but I dont see the change in the variables, I never tried process="@this, min, max"

Comment: In next questions, please also state what you tried and preferably with links to where you found the info. See [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar need and I implement this simple solution :
I create this function

```
function isMinOrMaxRangeFocus() {
                        if ($($('#sliderId .ui-slider-handle')[0]).hasClass('ui-state-focus')) return 'min';
                        if ($($('#sliderId .ui-slider-handle')[1]).hasClass('ui-state-focus')) return 'max';
                        return ('none');
                    }
```

And after you can use it at onstart like this :

```
<p:slider id="sliderId" for="sliderMin,sliderMax" range="true" >
                                        <p:ajax event="slideEnd" onstart="$('#whichSliderIs).val(isMinOrMaxRangeFocus());" process="@this,whichSliderIs,sliderMin,sliderMax" listener="#{myBean.myListener()}" />
                                    </p:slider>
                                    <h:inputHidden id="sliderMin" value="#{myBean.sliderMin}"/>
                                    <h:inputHidden id="sliderMax" value="#{myBean.sliderMax}"/>
                                    <h:inputText id="whichSliderIs" value="#{myBean.whichSliderIs}" style="display: none"/>
```

Know it's very easy to know which value is changed !